# Number of integers less than $x$ with $k$ prime divisors (not necessarily different)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let be $P_k = \{n | n = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k, p_i = \text{prime numbers not necessary different} |\}$

$P_1 = \text{set of primes }$,
$P_2 = \text{integers with exactly two primes factors}$, ....

We know that $|\{n \in P_1, n \leq x \}| = \pi(x) \sim x/\log x$-.

Is there any approximation for
$$ | \{ n \leq x | n \in P_k \} | = |\{ n \leq x | n = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k, p_i = \text{prime numbers not necessary different}\}|$$

Comment: Please see my answer and Barry Cipra's comment.  Which, if either, of us is reading the question correctly?  Please clarify.

Comment: For $k=2$, it looks like you are counting *semi-primes*. See https://oeis.org/A072000 for an asymptotic formula.  You might try doing some calculations and then searching OEIS for other values of $k$.

Comment: I think we can come up with one.  There are approximately $\pi(x)$ primes less than $x$ so there are a $\pi(x)^k$ numbers with $k$ of those prime factors.  So we need to rule out all those numbers that are $> x$.  I think with some recursive definitions based on that the larger primes have few multiples less then $x$ but the density of these large primes are less we can come up with an integral (possible double integral) to calculate that.  I don't think the exact formula will be easy to find but.... I think if one wants to we have a method to pursue.

Comment: So to be clear you are saying $125 = 5^3$ has $3$ prime factors.  And $75 = 3*5^2$ and $30 = 2*3*5$ all have $3$ prime factors.

Comment: @fleablood yes. I'm saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\pi_k(x)\sim\frac{x(\log\log x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!\log x}$$

Exact formula for $\pi_k(x)=P_k(x,0)$ here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297785/prime-counting-meissel-lehmer-is-there-a-general-formula/300060#300060

Comment: What is $\pi_k(x)$?

Comment: $\pi_k(x)$ is counting the number of numbers less than $x$ having exactly $k$ prime factors (not necessarily distinct). $\pi_1(x)$ is the classic prime counting function. Isn't it what you were looking for? The definition of $P_k(x,a)$ is in the link and is identical when you set $a=0$

Comment: Thanks for the aclaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), $\sigma_0(n)$, given in [OEIS A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005).  I didn't find anything about the asymptotic growth rate easily.  Note that it is $2$ whenever $n$ is prime, so you need to ask about the maximum up to $n$ or something like that.  [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) gives
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_0(k)}n\sim \log n+2\gamma-1$$

Comment: I think you're misreading the question here. As I understand it, the OP wants to fix a positive integer $k$ and then look at (and count) integers $n$ that are a product of $k$ primes. To invent some ad hoc notation, the OP is interested in asymptotic formulas for what I'll call $\pi_k(x)$, where $\pi_1$ is the ordinary prime-counting function.