# Distribution of composite numbers with $n$ prime factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Similar to how the Prime Number Theorem approximates the number of primes less than some value $x$, is there a theorem/function that approximates the number of composite numbers with exactly $n$ prime factors (counting multiplicity), less than $x$?

Comment: [The case of semiprimes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/841093/can-you-derive-a-formula-for-the-semiprime-counting-function-from-the-prime-numb). I'm convinced we have a decent question/answer for the general case, but so far I haven't found it.

Comment: This has been asked before.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254257/number-of-integers-less-than-x-with-k-prime-divisors-not-necessarily-differ.