# Why is the average number of divisors of the first $N$ natural numbers approximately $\log(N)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logarithms

In the textbook *An Illustrated Theory of Numbers*, the following problem appears:

[image]

I wrote up some Sage code to confirm this:

```
   def divisors(x):
    l = []
    for n in range(1,x+1):
        if x%n == 0:
            l.append(n)
    return len(l)


def sum_divisor_up_to_k(k):
    l = []
    for n in range(1,k+1):
        l.append(divisors(n))
    return sum(l)

def Average_up_to_j(j):
    return (sum_divisor_up_to_k(j)/j)


errors = [ abs(Average_up_to_j(x)-log(x).n()) for x in range(10,100) ]


for error in errors:
    print(error, '\n')
```

And lo and behold, the textbook is right about this. Their difference approaches zero. I am both surprised and amazed this is the case.

Why should $NA(N)$ approach $\log(N)$ as $N$ approaches infinity, and how is this picture helpful?

Comment: *Hint.* Rearrange the following double sum: $$NA(N) = \sum_{n\leq N} \sigma_0(n) = \sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{d\leq N}\mathbf{1}[\text{$d$ divides $n$}],$$ where $\mathbf{1}[\ldots]$ is the [indicator function notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).

Comment: in Hardy and Wright,   theorems 319 and 320. In the Fifth edition  this is pages 264-266

Comment: This is also covered in Tom Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* as Theorem $3.3$.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Csigma_%7B0%7D(i)%7D%7Bn%7D%5Capprox%20%5Clog(n)%24&p=1), there's this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3254305) which states "[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html) gives $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_0(k)}n\sim \log n+2\gamma-1$".

Comment: @SangchulLee I am trying to use the hint you provided, but I'm not sure how turning to double sum makes this any easier. Is there something special about the indicator function here? I am aware how to find $\sigma(x)$ for any given $x$, given its prime factorization is known, but not sure how this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

\begin{align*}
NA(N) = \sum_{n\leq N} \sigma_0(n) 
&= \sum_{n\leq N} \sum_{d\leq N} \mathbf{1}[\text{$d$ divides $n$}] \\
&= \sum_{d\leq N} \sum_{n\leq N} \mathbf{1}[\text{$n$ is a multiple of $d$}] \\
&= \sum_{d\leq N} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{d} \right\rfloor.
\end{align*}

In order to estimate the last sum, we invoke the following inequality:

$$ \int_{d}^{d+1} \frac{N}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x - 1
\leq \left\lfloor \frac{N}{d} \right\rfloor
\leq \int_{d-1}^{d} \frac{N}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

Summing the first inequality for $1 \leq d < N$ and the second one for $1 < d \leq N$, we get

$$ N \log N - N + 2 \leq NA(N) \leq N \log N + N. $$

Dividing both sides by $N$ proves the desired claim.

---

*Remark.* Writing

$$ A(N) = H_N - \sum_{d\leq N} \left\{ \frac{N}{d} \right\} \frac{1}{N} $$

and noting that $\sum_{d\leq N} \left\{ \frac{N}{d} \right\} \frac{1}{N} \to \int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\} \, \mathrm{d}x = 1 - \gamma$, we can also obtain a better estimate

$$ A(N) = \log N + 2\gamma - 1 + o(1) $$

as $N \to \infty$.